# The storage configuration for OAuth2 is missing when 'config_cache_enabled' is set to true

Tags: php, zend-framework2, oauth-2.0, access-token, laminas-api-tools

I'm using zf2 apigility in my web application. With production mode, if `config_cache_enabled` is `true` in `config/application.config.php`, I get this message error when requesting `access_token`:

> The storage configuration for OAuth2 is missing

If I set it to `false`, I get my access token.

So my problem is to have `config_cache_enabled` set to `true` and a successful request for getting the access token in production mode, due to best performance when configuration is cached. How to do that ?

This is my `zf-mvc-auth` configuration :

```
'zf-mvc-auth' => array(
        'authentication' => array(
            'adapters' => array(
                'CustomStorage' => array(
                    'adapter' => 'ZF\\MvcAuth\\Authentication\\OAuth2Adapter',
                    'storage' => array(
                        'storage' => 'Application\\Adapter\\OAuth\\CustomPdoAdapter',
                        'route' => '/oauth',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
```

This is my oauth2.local.php :

```
'zf-oauth2' => array(
        'db' => array(
            'dsn'      => 'mysql:dbname=mydatabase;host=localhost',
            'username' => 'root',
            'password' => '',
        ),
        'allow_implicit' => true,
        'access_lifetime' => 3600,
        'enforce_state'  => true,
        'storage'        => 'Application\Adapter\OAuth\CustomPdoAdapter',
        'storage_settings' => array(
           'user_table' => 'users',
        ),
         'options' => array(
            'always_issue_new_refresh_token' => true,
        ),
    ),
```

I think it is well configured.

Answer (score 1):

Did you setup your `zf-mvc-auth` correctly. In [the `module.config.php` you can read that you have to define a storage key](https://github.com/zfcampus/zf-mvc-auth/blob/master/config/module.config.php#L85). There is also written [how you can do this](https://github.com/zfcampus/zf-mvc-auth/blob/master/config/module.config.php#L89):

> To specify the storage instance, you may use one of two approaches:
>
> - Specify a "storage" subkey pointing to a named service or an array
>     of named services to use.
> - Specify an "adapter" subkey with the value "pdo" or "mongo", and
>     include additional subkeys for configuring a ZF\OAuth2\Adapter\PdoAdapter
>     or ZF\OAuth2\Adapter\MongoAdapter, accordingly. See the zf-oauth2
>     documentation for details.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on production mode and "config_cache_enabled" it's true, you need to **delete files** on `data/cache` folder